# Preventing long QComboBox from moving up

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am creating a drop-down menu in a Qt application with QComboBox. The issue is that if the QComboBox has many elements, when I click on the combo-box, the selected item is not lined up with the cursor. To demonstrate:

```
import string
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QComboBox

app = QApplication([])

widget = QComboBox()
for letter in string.ascii_letters:
    widget.addItem(letter)

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Gives:

[image]

Before clicking on the QComboBox, the selected item was 'a'. When I click on it, the QComboBox is moved up because it would otherwise not fit on the screen, and my cursor is in front of the 'p'.

I can see how this would make sense in a lot of cases, but in my specific application I want to avoid this behavior, even if it means that the bottom of the QComboBox will be truncated. When I click on the combo box, I want the cursor to be in front of the selected item. Is there any way to disable the upward movement of the QComboBox?

Comment: You could try setting the [max visible items](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) depending on how far above the bottom of your screen the mouse is? Someone might have a better solution than that though...

Comment: Unfortunately this option has no effect on Mac and GTK+

Comment: O, that's a shame...

Comment: You can get the list view with the [`QComboBox::view`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#view) method. You could try messing with that. Maybe set a maximum height or something. See if that helps. Probably not the prettiest solution though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in setting the item you can do that with the

```
QComboBox.setItem ()
QComboBox.setCurrentIndex ()
```

methods.